# word order; each the grave vs the each grave

Tags: word-order

is an order of the words correct in the middle of this sentence? "A board was stretched *over each the grave* and people, in groups of 10, were standing on it."

Shouldn't it be *over the each grave*?

Comment: We don't combine "the" and "each". Either one of these words sufficiently qualifies the noun; together, they clash.  http://www.google.com/search?q=clash+definition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

*the* doesn't belong here - there is more than one grave so with 'the grave' it would never be clear which one is meant.

Correct would be to say

> A board was stretched over each grave and people, in groups of 10, were standing on it.

Or:

> A board was stretched over each of the graves and people, in groups of 10, were standing on it.

Comment: But if there were only one grave, you'd say "A board was stretched over the grave, etc."

Answer (score 0):

"each" is an article word, that is it takes the postion of the article "the". You can't use two article words.

Not: the a man, the each boy, each the boy.

Such combinations are nonsense. If you understand the meaning of "the/a/each" it is not difficult to see why you don't use two article words before a noun.

Comment: Now I see it, thank you. The same case is with indefinite article "a" and numeral "one" There is either "a boy" or "one boy" not "a one boy"